# Create raster shaded relief map in GDAL from ASCII files

Tags: gdal

I have just installed GDAL ver 1.11.4 and Python ver 2.7. I am trying to create a relief map using Ordnance Survey Terrain 50 ASCII data using `gdal_merge.py`.

Being new to GDAL, I don't know how to handle the many `.asc` files in the dataset. What are the tools available in GDAL to help transform these into a format like GeoTiff and merge the many separate files into one larger raster?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a color shaded relief map from you `.asc` files, than you can use `gdaldem` as described below.

Firstly you will need to create a text file (`color_relief.txt') with the elevation classes and corresponding RGB values. For instance:

```
140 90 220 90
200 240 250 160
250 230 220 170
300 220 220 220
350 250 250 250
```

Where the first column is the Z (elevation value) and the subsequent three columns are the RGB values.

Then using `gdaldem`:

```
gdaldem color-relief input.asc color_relief.txt color_relief_output.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ordnance Survey Terrain 50](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html) is distributed as a set of 10 km x 10 km tiles, each labeled geographically by a two-letter key ([map here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid.svg)). There is a hierarchy to the data directory so that each tile is a directory, and within that directory there are a set of smaller tiles. I am going to assume that you just downloaded the entire dataset and have unzipped it somewhere, called `root_OS50_terrain`. Within that directory there is a `data` directory and `licence.txt`.

```
/root_OS50_terrain/
  | data/
     | hp/
     | hu/
     ...
     | tr/
        | tr01_OST50GRID_20160726.zip
        | tr02_OST50GRID_20160726.zip
        | ....
```

Let's say you only want the `tr` 10km x 10km tile. It might be easiest to merge the ascii files into a single raster and then transform that merged dem into a hillshade.

```
$ cd root_OS50_terrain/data/tr  # go into the tile directory
$ unzip '*.zip' -d tr_unzip     # unzip all zip files into a new directory
$ gdal_merge.py tr_unzip/*.asc -o tr_tile.tif # merge all ascii files into a geotiff
$ gdaldem hillshade tr_tile.tif tr_tile_hillshade.tif
```

If you need a single raster representing all the two-letter tiles, then do this procedure (except hillshade) for each 10km tile, merge these DEMs, then hillshade that merged DEM.